error in https://api.videosdk.live/infra/v1/meetings/init-config
I'm stuck with a problem rendering videoSdk, I implemented it and it works well in the development environment, but when it goes to the web server the video doesn't work and it shows me an error in the api "https://api.videosdk. live/infra/v1/meetings/init-config" it says the token is missing or something like that, has anyone ever had this problem?
error in call:
https://api.videosdk.live/infra/v1/meetings/init-config

Hello:) Please provide the exact error so we can identify the problem.

Did you find out the solution? If yes, please share.
